# Why default parser (using commons-cli) does not throw exception when option is not recognized?

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

I would like to have a printed usage help message, when an option which is specified as a program argument is not valid (not available in the predefined options list).

```
      CommandLineParser parser = new BasicParser();
    try {
        CommandLine line = parser.parse(getOptions(), args);
    }
    catch( ParseException exp ) {
        getLogger().info("Invalid command line option name. "+exp.getMessage());
        HelpFormatter hf = new HelpFormatter();
        hf.printHelp("destDir", getOptions());
        return false;
    }       
    return true;
```

I type as a parameter the 'Test' string. I was thinking, that invalid options cause the parser to throw ParseException, however they do not. How can I achieve that behaviour? Is it possible with this library at all? Now it just omits parameters which are not valid.

**UPDATE**
Actually it throws exception when option has a '-' prefix. So '-Test' cause throwing an exception, but 'Test' does not. My question anyway is still valid, how to force parser to throw an exception on an invalid parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command lines have two types of entry other than the program name, Options (which are specified with a `-` or `--`) and what I will call parameters (which probably have a better name but I don't know what it is!) which don't have a prefix. For example, for `ls`:

`ls -la foo`

The options are `-l` and `-a`, and parameter is `foo` (the directory to list). When you parse a command line with commons-cli it *only* cares about the options, it ignores everything else. Which is why it doesn't fail if you add `Test` (not an option) but does if you add `-Test`.

Comment: Ok, i understand this, but i thought that in commons-cli library i would be able to validate ALL command lines argument

Comment: Sadly, not as far as I know :( Which is why you can often tell when something uses commons-cli - because everything is a `--` option :)

Answer (score 0):

Although answer provided by [adamreeve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6566965/adamreeve) is really fine and I accept it, I've decided to extend default parser capabilities to prevent typing invalid option even without '-' or '--' symbols. I made my own custom parser :

```
public class StrictParser extends Parser {

    @Override
    protected String[] flatten(Options opts, String[] arguments, boolean stopAtNonOption) {
        return arguments;
    }

    @Override
    public CommandLine parse(Options options, String[] arguments, boolean stopAtNonOption) throws ParseException {

        CommandLine cmd = null;
        List<String> tokenList = Arrays.asList(flatten(getOptions(), arguments, stopAtNonOption));
        ListIterator<String> iterator = tokenList.listIterator();

        boolean eatTheRest = false;
        setOptions(options);
        cmd = super.parse(options, arguments, stopAtNonOption);

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String token = (String) iterator.next();
            if (!token.startsWith("--") && !token.startsWith("-")) {
                if (stopAtNonOption) {
                        throw new UnrecognizedOptionException("Unrecognized option: " + token +". Every option must start with '--' or '-'", token);
                }
            } else {
                eatTheRest = true;
            }

            if (eatTheRest) {
                iterator.next();
            }
        }
        return cmd;
    }
}
```

In this solution any cli parameters typed without '--' or '-' throw UnrecognizedOptionException. This is no perfect solution, but it show how it can be done, and can be a good starting point to other solutions. For instance we could accept options without '--' and '-' but check if that option is correct. Then we need to change

```
        if (stopAtNonOption) {
                throw new UnrecognizedOptionException("Unrecognized option: " + token +". Every option must start with '--' or '-'", token);
        }
```

to

```
        if (stopAtNonOption) {                  
            if(!getOptions().hasOption(token)){                     
                throw new UnrecognizedOptionException(
                        "Unrecognized option: " + token, token);
            }
        }
```

(ignore this ugly three nested ifs ;))
This also accepts only one argument per option,but as I've mentioned it's only starting point to implement other modifications to default parser

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can , you have to create custom Exception like:

```
public class ParseException extends Exception{
        ParseException(String msg){
             super(msg);  
        }
}
```

And into code :

```
CommandLineParser parser = new BasicParser();
    try {
        CommandLine line = parser.parse(getOptions(), args);
    }
    catch( Exception exp ) {
       throw new ParseException("Invalid Arguments");
    }       
    return true;
```

And above method should throw

```
throws ParseException
```

So its caller if pass invalid argument will get ParseException

Comment: your solution it is more like defining new exception. But in my case ParseException is not throw from parse method, when args contains invalid options.

Comment: @ArturSkrzydło Please read Answer carefully second part of answer containing you code with modification and third part of answer showing change  in calling of method

Comment: you've created new Exception and throw it when ParseExcpetion is thrown from parse method. It has not any sense in this case, because i never reach the catch statement when i define argument which is not valid.

Comment: @ArturSkrzydło now see the answer if parse get exception it will throw ParseException

Comment: Look at my question again - 'I was thinking, that invalid options cause parser to throw ParseException, however it's not.' It means that when i type invalid option name then ParseException is not thrown. So your solution is pointless. Additionaly what is sense in rethrowing exception. I could just ommit try-catch statement and define it in 'throws'  in method declaration