# Strict command line parser

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, apache-commons-cli

in connection with this [Apache command line parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686809/apache-command-line-parser/54687180?noredirect=1#comment96164270_54687180) (Since it is completely out topic). Is there a way to strictly follow the short hand. Like `-m` and not `-multi` or for long name it should be `--multiply` and not `--multi`?

Since, as per post, commons-cli (Apache) evaluates both `-m` and `-multi` as the same. What i was thinking is that only `-m` or `--multiply` should be accepted.

I am using Apache's Commons CLI (commons-cli-1.3.1)

Answer (score 0):

for the information of everyone, i got an idea on how to go about this problem. take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082191/why-default-parser-using-commons-cli-does-not-throw-exception-when-option-is-n). I got the idea on the answers.

Basically what you want to do is extend the `DefaultParser` class and override `parse()` method, add some of your logic in checking `args` and process to `DefaultParser`'s `parse` (via `super.parse(...)`). In that way you can retain the original behavior of `DefaultParser` whilst adding logics on top of it.

Hope this helps someone.

Credits to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40396355/1545664) @Artur Skrzydło